# MATLAB Game with GUIDE

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm creating a game (similar to Space Invaders) in MATLAB using Guide, where the player's ship is controlled by an accelerometer. So far, my GUI is nearly complete and I have managed to import an image of a ship and move it along the x-axis of main axes with the accelerometer. However, I cannot get enemy ships to be generated on the axes at the same time. After adding just a second image, the first one never generates. The code that loads the images is as follows:

```
handles.spaceShipImg = flipdim(imread('spaceship.jpg'),1);
handles.enemyShipImg = flipdim(imread('enemy1.jpg'),1);
```

Here is the part where I attempt to display the images:

```
handles.step = handles.step + handles.gx;   %handles.gx is the reading from the accelerometer
axes(handles.magaxes)
image([handles.gx+handles.step 0.7+handles.gx+handles.step],[0 0.7],handles.spaceShipImg);
image([8 8.7],[8 8.7],handles.enemyShipImg);
set(gca,'YDir','normal')
axis([0 10 0 10]);
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to just use rectangular objects, and then paint them with an image instead. I also have to create collision detection, and I'm not sure how to implement that with images or rectangles. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `hold on` and `hold off` commands to prevent the axes from refreshing when painting the 2nd image.  Put the `hold on` after `axes(handles.magaxes)` and use 'hold off` after axis([0 10 0 10]);

Comment: I eventually figured this out on my own, but thanks for taking the time to answer. Hold on is the solution.